Не работает intent-filter в Android-приложении
Пытаюсь добиться того, чтобы по ссылке пользователь сразу открывал Android-приложение.
Что я сделал:

Добавил intent-filter в AndroidManifest.xml:

<activity
    android:name=".ShareFolderActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:scheme="https"
            android:host="test.mydomen.ru"
            android:pathPrefix="/api/v1/folder/share/" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>


Добавил в корень папки проекта на хосте папку .well-known;
В неё поместил файл assetlinks.json:

[
  {
    "relation": [
      "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
    ],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.example.myapp",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
        "мой ключ SHA256 в формате A1:B2:C3..."
      ]
    }
  }
]

Проблема:
При установке приложения кликаю по ссылке, к примеру в телеге:
https://test.mydomen.ru/api/v1/folder/share/
но ссылка открывается в браузере — т. е. intent не срабатывает.
Захожу в "Приложения" → "О приложении" и вижу:

Захожу в "Открывать по умолчанию", а там всё включено (есть поддерживаемая ссылка):

После этого начинает открывать ссылку в приложении, но в "О приложении" по прежнему настройки по умолчанию не установлены.
В чём может быть причина такого поведения?

как задать хороший вопрос. начните, пожалуйста, с формулировки заголовка.

Не приводите версию Android, предполагаю 12+. Согласно документации: "Note: Starting in Android 12 (API level 31), a generic web intent resolves to an activity in your app only if your app is approved for the specific domain contained in that web intent. If your app isn't approved for the domain, the web intent resolves to the user's default browser app instead." https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

В андроиде 12+ действительно ввели доп ограничения и по идеи без правильного /.well-known/assetlinks.json ссылки не откроются через приложение. Но у меня таже проблема, есть фильтр есть /.well-known/assetlinks.json а все равно в браузере открывает. Причем согласно логам adb logcat девайс даже не запрашивает /.well-known/assetlinks.json

upd должно работать. я только добавил autoVerify и удалил android:pathPrefix из своего фильтра и у меня взлетело
